# HTML/CSS in WordPress custom theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am making a website in WordPress using a theme called Hueman. I want my whole site in fullscreen and get rid of the borders on the side (I'll show in a picture).
Can't find where to edit this.

[image]

I need to remove the borders 1 and 2 and make it fullscreen and responsive on other browsers/devices.

Comment: Your template doen't have any option to do this? Most of templates have this option.

Comment: Wait, where is that option? I've been told to look into the theme's folder and try to edit the .css files. But I'm a beginner when it comes down to html/css. I've tried copy pasting some codes from internet but nothing helped.

Comment: If you don't have the option, it will be better to show a link of the site, because if not it is kind of difficult to show you how to do it.

Comment: Don't look into css! just check your site setting or theme setting or option. Sometimes it append to main menu.(All of these are in admin panel)

Comment: How do I link you the site? I'm hosting it with wamp on localhost.

Comment: I've looked on my dashboard and tried looking for it in the setting under "appearance" but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding this as custom css (tested and confirmed just now on latest heuman version)

```
.wrapper,
.container,
.container-inner {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

**Note:**
Don't make changes to original theme files, preferably make a child theme or else use custom css option

Comment: Hello. Thank you for helping me. Although this didn't completely solve my problem as it seemed a little bit buggy on the right side of the screen. I did manage to fix this though I'll add a comment with pictures for better understanding

Comment: here is a picture of what your solution gave me:
https://gyazo.com/4dd98b66ca614bb944ae9c38bb2e0306

This is what I was looking for.
https://gyazo.com/1d366f4f530aa07ebdf839ff6677fd9c

I done this by going into main.min into css files and go to container.inner and removing the max-width.

But thanks a lot for your solution aswell!

Comment: it's better not to edit main.css, give me link to your site so that i can suggest better, also please upvote & select this answer as correct if it was :)

Comment: I did upvote. And I can't link you my siet. It's on localhost, how do I host this quickly?

Comment: upvote needs up arrow to be clicked, you marked tick (that's good), but upvote is pending :D

Comment: for hosting, I'm not sure how much skilled you're at hosting wordpress, I can provide you with hosing space + development service too if u need

Answer (score -1):

As told in the comments, there is a function in most themes (mostly non-free themes) to edit the appearance without changing any code. Often themes install this tweak-UI in the controll panel on the left, using it's own name, adding sth like "options" (e.g. "[myThemeName] options"). Be sure to check that before you change anything in the css-files.

If there isn't any options-menu you should check the structure of the php-file you want to load. Mostly you'll find sth like a "container"-div, which should be one of the first div-instances. Take the id/class of that div and add a rule to the css file, making its width to 100%. Before you add a new rule first check if there is already a rule declaring sth for this div.

Hope that helped you!

Comment: As you said this theme is having option to disable boxed layout in the back end.

Comment: Correct. So why was my answer downvoted?

Comment: May be by someone who is not aware of this feature/theme